# UPDATE with Nested Query

Tags: mysql

This is what i've tried

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM music GROUP BY songalbum) 
SET albumID = (SELECT albumID FROM albumList GROUP BY album ) 
WHERE songalbum = albumList.album
```

this give the error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

```
UPDATE music 
SET albumID = (SELECT albumID FROM albumList ) 
WHERE albumID = NULL

UPDATE music 
SET albumID = (SELECT albumID FROM albumList )
WHERE albumID = NULL 
  AND songalbum = (select album FROM albumList)
```

both run but have no affected rows.

I am trying to populate the albumID in the music table with the albumIDs that are in the albumList table.

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? PHPMyAdmin suggests the first. The lack of `;` suggests SQL-Server. Which one do you use?

Comment: There should be ; at the end of each statement but when I copied them over I didn't add them in. i am using phpMyAdmin. i had the GROUP BY in there as well to make it only look at unique albums because the music table has multiple songs per album

Comment: I removed the "sql-server" tag. The error "every derived table .." is a mysql error.

Answer (score 3):

If it is MySQL, you can do this with a simple join:

```
UPDATE music AS m
  JOIN albumList AS a
    ON m.songalbum = a.album 
SET m.albumID = a.albumID 
WHERE m.albumID IS NULL ;
```

---

You could use a correlated subquery for this (similar to your 2nd attempt) but I wouldn't suggest it for MySQL. Less efficient and more complicated as it needs an additional condition in the `WHERE` clause to protect from updating `music.albumID` with null, for rows that have no related album:

```
UPDATE music AS m
SET albumID = (SELECT albumID FROM albumList AS a WHERE m.songalbum = a.album) 
WHERE albumID IS NULL
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM albumList AS a WHERE m.songalbum = a.album) ;
```

Comment: Well your suggestion worked perfectly. Is there not a way to make it happen with a nested SELECT statement?

Comment: You could use subqueries but it would be more complicated. It's better to use join for update in MySQL. I can update my answer if you like.

Comment: Wow, amazing. I knew it wasn't supposed to be as hard as I was making it. Thank you very much for your help! May the SQL gods be ever in your favor.